# Restoring iPhone backup from iTunes taking too long

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup

I got a new iPhone today to replace my broken one and I am trying to restore the backup from iTunes. I had around 50 GB of content in my old iPhone.

The remaining time to finish the backup started in 2 hours, and is steadily increasing (to about 27 hours at the time of this post).

Is there something wrong with my system?

I am recovering an iOS 9.3.2 backup to an iPhone 6 (64 GB) on a Mac running macOS 10.11.6 (El Capitan) on a 2013 iMac. I am using the lightning cable to restore the backup, and not over Wi-Fi.

Comment: How long did it take finally?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make sure that you have the latest version of iTunes (Currently v12.4.2) installed on your mac so that it supports the latest version of iOS.
Secondly, you can't restore an iPhone with a later version of iOS (iOS 9.3.2) to an iPhone with an older version (for instance, iOS 8.x). So make sure you've updated your new iPhone 6 to the latest version of iOS which is currently 9.3.3, then try it again.

I recommend you read [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203271) and also [this one](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203434) so you'll get more information.

I hope I could help you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Besdies the reasons that Parsa Samet said, restoring backup from iTunes taking so long may be caused by iTunes errors.

I encountered this problem when I was restoring my backup for iPhone 5s to my new iPhone 7(which running iOS 11). Took 8 hours but never end...

Finally I used a tool named iMyFone D-Port Pro made this. The whole process tool about 20 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

You **NEED** to remove internet protocol v6 from Windows 10 computer for iTunes to run faster.  After I removed the file it went from 5 hours to 1 hour.  Get a hold of a Windows 10 pc and remove connection file ipv6, easy as that.

Comment: How does this address the problem?  The OP isn't using a Windows PC.  Please [edit] your answer to either address the problem or explain, with supporting info, you believe moving to a Windows 10 PC will solve the problem.  - From Review